# Pass id from home page in edit page

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I want to pass id from home page to edit page . i can see it in home page .
th code is :

```
 <li ng-repeat="data in data">
        {{data.ID}}
        {{data.subject}}
        <a href="#/edit?data={{data.ID}}">Edit</a>
 </li>
```

here i can't see the id page with data binding ?
**edit page**

```
{{data.ID}}
<form>
    <input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="name" ng-model="subject"/>
</form>
```

the question is how to edit data with specefic Id ?
Thx

Comment: use a service, you pass the data id there, when the new template comes gets that id from the service.

If not you can use what you are doing and get it from the urlstring

Comment: thx @santiago , can u show me an example of urlstring ?

Answer (score 1):

a few questions if you don't mind; are you under the same controller? Can we see the full code of your app?

There are a few ways to send parameters from one view to another, I'll give you a few links that helped me:

Angular in 50 examples. On the second part, you can find the whole logic for doing this:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TRrL5j3MIvo&list=PLmsMImsNUyoH9Awy8nl5Hrskk7sDG1Dtg&index=1
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6J08m1H2BME&index=2&list=PLmsMImsNUyoH9Awy8nl5Hrskk7sDG1Dtg

AngularJs Documentation. Here you have a simple example of how to apply routing and parameters:
https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07

I hope this helps you.

Regards!